# Ошибка в билдере

Tags: c++builder

при запуске  в билдере,создания Form и так далее, главное Unit хорошо создает, появляется сообщение об ошибке:
Unable to rename "C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Bin\bcb.$$$" to "C:\Program Files\Borland\CBuilder6\Bin\bcb.dro"
Что это такое???

Comment: у меня Windows 7

Comment: Это значит, что у него, запущенного от вашего пользователя, не хватает прав на запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Builder6 как то староват для windows 7(имхо), возможно семерка просто не поддерживает его, попробуй:

- запустить Builder с админскими правами.
- поставить режим совместимости с xp.
- лучше всего поставь себе поновее версию, например embarcadero xe2

Первый пункт должен помочь, эта ошибка чаще всего и вылезает при отсутствии прав.

Comment: Я ставил Builder6 на  семерку. Там какая-то адаптационная процедура должна быть проведена.